# Angular Universal not rendering route

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I'm having a problem with Angular Universal, although all guides are different (the official one seems outdated aswell) I've managed to run node.js server with server side rendering.
There's still a huge problem which I can't solve, because I actually have no idea on what's going on

This is the `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
            appId: 'ta-un-certificate'
        }),
        RouterModule.forRoot([{
            path: '', loadChildren: './page/page.module#PageModule'
        }], {
            enableTracing: false,
            useHash: false
        }),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    providers: [
        SeoService,
        DataService, {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

It simply loads another module, `PageModule` with its components and stuff

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([{
            path: ':name/:id', component: PageComponent
        }, {
            path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: RedirectComponent
        }])
    ],
    declarations: [
        RedirectComponent,
        PageComponent,
        BannerComponent,
        BodyComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ]
})
export class PageModule {
}
```

For the server part, I made another module, `app.server.module.ts` which is the one used by node.js

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AppModule,
        ServerModule,
        ModuleMapLoaderModule,
        ServerTransferStateModule
    ],
    providers: [
        SeoService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {
}
```

The problem is that if I try to call a route from node.js server, eg. `http://localhost:4000/foo/bar`, the node.js server console prints out a huge error, starting with this:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
[...]
```

(it's really huge, if u need something please ask)
And page doesn't get rendered, as from cURL I get only `<app-root><router-outlet></router-outlet></app-root>` inside html body.

I think I've checked so many guides that I've completely lost the right way to do it, but cloning [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) seems doing what I'm expecting from Universal

Comment: Are you using navigator in your code? Or a library that uses it? This won't be defined server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching on compiled `server.js` script, the one executed by node, it seemed like there was an error inside Translator. So I focused searching for issues between html rendering and Translation pipe, but then I've just found a `navigator.language.split` inside a service (app wasn't built by me). Moved that control inside a `isPlatformServer` block solved my issue.

This was the breaking part of code

```
private _language = navigator.language.split('-')[0];

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
}
```

Which I edited as following

```
private _language;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
            private _http: HttpClient) {

    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        this._language = 'en';
    } else {
        this._language = navigator.language.split('-')[0];
    }
}
```

Fixed the issue