# Angular Universal rendering only router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-universal, universal

Before I share this problem I've searched on google and I don't seem to find the problem, here is a glimpse of the links I visited to solve my problem:

[Angular Universal not rendering route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48923227/angular-universal-not-rendering-route)

[Angular Universal not rendering content inside of router-outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368564/angular-universal-not-rendering-content-inside-of-router-outlet)

[Angular universal rendering for some routes only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464614/angular-universal-rendering-for-some-routes-only)

I don't know why the content inside router-outlet is not showing that's what I see:

```
<app-root _nghost-sc17="" ng-version="14.2.0" ng-server-context="other">
<router-outlet _ngcontent-sc17=""></router-outlet><!----></app-root>
```

I don't have any errors in the console or terminal.

**server.ts:**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import {existsSync} from 'fs';
import {join} from 'path';

import {AppServerModule} from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/food-recipe-front/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

tsconfig.server.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "target": "es2019",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ]
}
```

**routes.ts:**

```
{path:'', component:HomeComponent, children: [
    { path:'home', component:HomeFrontComponent},
    { path: 'recipes', component:IndexRecipeComponent},
    { path: 'recipes/:strCategory', component:IndexRecipeComponent},
    { path: 'recipe-detail/:id', component:RecipeDetailComponent},
    { path: 'blogs', component:IndexBlogsComponent},
    { path: 'blog-detail/:id', component:BlogDetailComponent},
    { path: 'privacy', component:PrivacyComponent},
    { path: 'about-us', component:AboutUsComponent},
    { path: 'contact', component:ContactComponent},
  ]},
```

Any help will be appreciated. If you want more code just tell me. Thank you.

Comment: What backend stack are you using? Additionally, how do you run your angular app (`npm run serve:ssr`)? Do you experience this for all routes/pages?

Comment: Im using NestJs for backend, yes it happens for all the routes even the static ones. and Yes I run the app using npm run serve:ssr

Comment: no, until this day, unfortunately